# Algorithm for task redistribution

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one with tasks to distribute (task id, current assignee id, days in progress, days since last update), another with assignees (assignee id, currents amount of tasks).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

tasks = pd.DataFrame()

tasks['task_id'] = np.arange(1, 101)
tasks['task_id'] = tasks['task_id'].astype('object')

tasks['assignee_id'] = np.random.randint(low=1, high=11, size=100)
tasks['assignee_id'] = tasks['assignee_id'].astype('object')

tasks['days_in_prog'] = np.random.randint(low=11, high=16, size=100)
tasks['days_after_upd'] = np.random.randint(low=6, high=11, size=100)

tasks = tasks.sort_values(['days_in_prog', 'days_after_upd'], ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

tasks.head(10)
```

Output:

```
    task_id assignee_id days_in_prog days_after_upd
0   28  4   15  10
1   59  5   15  10
2   61  9   15  10
3   64  8   15  9
4   90  2   15  9
5   97  2   15  9
6   21  6   15  8
7   57  5   15  8
8   72  4   15  7
9   78  5   15  7
```

```
assignees = pd.DataFrame()

assignees['assignee_id'] = np.arange(1, 11)
assignees['assignee_id'] = assignees['assignee_id'].astype('object')

assignees['tasks'] = np.random.randint(low=5, high=16, size=10)

assignees = assignees.sort_values('tasks').reset_index(drop=True)

assignees
```

Output:

```
    assignee_id tasks
0   4   5
1   7   5
2   2   9
3   5   9
4   10  9
5   9   11
6   3   12
7   1   13
8   6   14
9   8   15
```

Now I'm looking for way to equally distribute tasks among assignees with few conditions:

1. current assignee != new assignee;
2. start with tasks which longer in progress;
3. start from assignees with less tasks;

I started from merging frames and creating function:

```
df = tasks.merge(assignees, on='assignee_id')

def new_assignee_func(row):
    if row

df['new_assignee'] = df.apply(new_assignee_func, axis=1)
```

But I can't find right algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why do you have `.astype('object')` calls? Are these intended to copy the column?

Comment: @SteeleFarnsworth thank you! Cause in real there are long ids with digits and letters. I have `.astype('object')` there to prevent operating them like integers.